# Does build prevent a model's before_create from firing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two models:

```
Room
RoomMembers
```

..

```
class Room
  before_create  :add_room_member

  def add_room_member
    self.room_members.build(:user_id => self.user.id)
  end
```

Then....

```
 class RoomMember
    before_create :default_values

    def default_values
      Rails.logger.info 'STUFF'
    end
```

When a new Room is created. The RoomMember before_create default values method is not firing.... Why is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

build is essentially an alias for new, where it instantiates the object, but does not save it. Since creating an object in Rails is just instantiating and saving the object, you are missing the save part when using build. Looking at your example, I think it would make more sense to add a room member *after* the room has been created, not before. You can then use create for this, and it should fire the RoomMember callback.

```
class Room
  after_create  :add_room_member

  def add_room_member
    self.room_members.create(:user_id => self.user.id)
  end
```

Comment: I'm reminded of the line from [Murder by Death](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0074937/): "A room filled with empty people."